# List domain controller count using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the number (count) of domain controllers in the domain. See below example code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -Force
(Get-ADDomainController -Filter "*" | Select-Object Name).Count
2
```

However when running the command in a domain with a single domain controller (count 1) there is no output.

```
(Get-ADDomainController -Filter "*" | Select-Object Name).Count
```

No output. Why is the 'Count' not shown as 1 with a single DC? What am I missing?

Comment: there is a known glitch with the `.Count` property when the $var is not a collection. the fix is to FORCE the $Var to be an array with something like >>> `@(Get-NoneOrOneOrMoreItems).Count` <<< that forces the result to be an array for zero/one/many items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$tc = 0
(Get-ADForest).Domains | ForEach {
 $tc += (Get-ADDomain -Identity $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ReplicaDirectoryServers).Count
}
$tc
```

- Get the domains of AD forest.
- Get The Replica Domain Controllers on each domain and add their count to the $tc variable.
- Return total count.

Comment: This is a better approach

Comment: If you like the answer, please also upvote it by clicking ^ looking button. Thanks.